# On submit, JSON data returns: "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am pulling in JSON data to populate two separate select fields (country and city).

When submitting the form I get the:

`Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

I have tried resetting the data using:

```
data.countries = data[0];
data = data[0];
```

before / after and it returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here is a snippet of the code I am using to retrieve the data

```
$.ajax({
    url: myAPI,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {

    $.each(data.countries, function (index, value) {
      country.append('<option value="' + value.name + '">' + value.name +'</option>');
    });

    country.on('change', function() {
        var self = $(this).val();

        city.find('option').remove();
        for(var i = 0; i < data.countries.length; i++) {
            if(data.countries[i].name == self) {
                $.each(data.countries[i].metroAreas, function (index, value) {
                  city.append('<option value="' + value.name+'">' + value.name +'</option>');
                });
            }
        }
    });
  } 

});
```

Comment: Are you sure `data.countries` is an `array` and not an `object`?

Comment: Also, if the errors are thrown when submitting the form, you are probably running some code. Which is it?

Comment: @Diego, attempting to access `.length` on an object will return undefined, not throw a `TypeError`, if the object is in fact defined, and if the object is not defined, a `ReferenceError` will be thrown

Comment: @AndrewMairose, you are right, I didn't think it through

Answer (score 1):

You should to tell jQuery to parse the result as JSON using the [`dataType` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

When omitted jQuery will guess the data type based on the `Content-Type` response header. It's a common problem that the server doesn't set this header or is setting it incorrectly (eg to `text/html`).

```
$.ajax({
    url: myAPI,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

    $.each(data.countries, function (index, value) {
      country.append('<option value="' + value.name + '">' + value.name +'</option>');
    });

    country.on('change', function() {
        var self = $(this).val();

        city.find('option').remove();
        for(var i = 0; i < data.countries.length; i++) {
            if(data.countries[i].name == self) {
                $.each(data.countries[i].metroAreas, function (index, value) {
                  city.append('<option value="' + value.name+'">' + value.name +'</option>');
                });
            }
        }
    });   } 

});
```